# Android EditText android:text not working

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

```
EditText  
android:textSize="18.0sp" 
android:textColor="@color/red" 
android:id="@id/et_server_url" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0.0dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip" 

android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="50.0dip" 
android:text="@string/serverurl" 
android:layout_weight="0.8" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logo" 
android:layout_below="@id/et_email" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:enabled="false" />
```

In this code, Text is not displaying .

Note: I have to change this only in the layout. I didn't have any java files.so

Comment: Can you put your code.

Comment: I have edited my question. in mobile i can't able to paste code so only now can you able to view it ?

Comment: @crammeur please help me

Comment: its very urgent. please anyone help me

Comment: I suggest you to replace `EditText` by `Textview` because editable of `EditText` is deprecated.

Comment: @crammeur no i can't change it. EditText is must. please suggest any . I have used inputType=none

Comment: You can use `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: @crammeur i m trying it... text is not visible when I use android:text .. why ?

Comment: Is because you have `android:visibility="gone"`

Comment: @crammeur fantastic you saved my time. now I can't able to edit it after using enabled false. and now I have removed visibility gone... then how to make EditText invisible?

Comment: <EditText android:textSize="18.0sp" android:textColor="@color/red" android:id="@id/et_server_url" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="50.0dip" android:text="@string/serverurl" android:layout_weight="0.8" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logo" android:layout_below="@id/et_email" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:enabled="false" />  @crammeur now my code is this... text is not visible why?

Comment: @crammeur please only one help... my text is not there in EditText field.... its blank even after adding android:text so please suggest any

Comment: @crammeur text alone need to display. please help me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

in programmatically

```
setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

or

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this edit text inside a RelativeLayout. So, remove this property and add height.

Remove this:-

```
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
```

And Add this:-

```
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You will be good to go.

And use,

```
EditText et_server_url = findViewById(R.id.et_server_url);
et_server_url.setEnabled(false); //To make it disabled
```

and

```
et_server_url.setEnabled(true); //to make it enabled
```

Comment: in EditText when we are giving android:text its not working... no text is shown there but we can able to add text, color applying

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
<EditText
        android:id="@id/et_server_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_email"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logo"
        android:background="@drawable/background_editext"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:paddingLeft="20.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="20.0dip"
        android:text="@string/serverurl"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="18.0sp" />
```

you're hiding yout `EditText` that is why you can't see or edit it

Comment: even after adding this the given android:text is not visibling

Comment: > <EditText android:textSize="18.0sp" android:textColor="@color/red" android:id="@id/et_server_url" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="50.0dip" android:text="@string/serverurl" android:layout_weight="0.8" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logo" android:layout_below="@id/et_email" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:enabled="false" />  see this in this i can't able to view the text which is given in android:text .. please help us

Comment: @GoSuganSoft can you show the screenshot of your screen? 
Is everything except Edit text is rendering? or nothing is rendering at all on the preview screen?

Answer (score 0):

bro your code working you can check `android:text="@string/text"` to `android:text="text"`
use hardcore string and check coz i am copy your code its working fine ...

and generally edittext use `android:hint` not `android:text`

and you can also set `editable="false"` in  `android:hint` using...

check its may help you...otherwise tell me ..